# ggplot - can I plot all data in each facet whilst split on another variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a graph of accounts over time split by account type and by year but I want the whole of the data to be in each facet but just in the background if it's not the bit I want to concentrate on.

Using the below dummy data, if I want to just do accounts over time by account type that shows what I want it to show.

```
df1 <- data.frame(acc_type=rep(c("cash", "credit"), each=10),
                 year = as.factor(rep(2019, each = 20)),
                 x_date=seq(10),
                 accounts=runif(20, 1000, 10000))


df1$acc_type2 <- df1$acc_type

ggplot(df1, aes(x_date,accounts, group=acc_type)) + 
  geom_line(data=df1[,3:5], aes(x=x_date, y=accounts, group=acc_type2), colour="grey") +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ acc_type, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

However, when I introduce year the data goes a bit funny

```
df2 <- data.frame(acc_type=rep(c("cash", "credit"), each=10),
                  year = as.factor(rep(2020, each = 20)),
                 x_date=seq(10),
                 accounts=runif(20, 1000, 10000))

df2$acc_type2 <- df2$acc_type

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df3$year2 <- df3$year


ggplot(df3, aes(x_date,accounts, group=acc_type,colour= year)) + 
  geom_line(data=df3[,-(1:2)], aes(x=x_date, y=accounts, group=acc_type2, colour = year2), colour="grey") +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ acc_type, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Then the data looks like it's not being grouped correctly, any help on how I can group it properly and put the data that's not as important to the background would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after. The trick is to not select the facet grouping variable in the second data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ggplot(data=df3, aes(x=x_date, y=accounts)) + 
  geom_line(data = select(df3, -acc_type),
            aes(group = interaction(acc_type2,year)), color = "gray") +
  geom_line(aes(color= year)) + 
  facet_wrap(~acc_type, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian that's perfect, exactly what I needed!